# Initial value problems with step functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

In my book I have the following problem:

$y'' + 4y = sin(t) + u_\pi(t)sin(t-\pi)$  where   $y(0)=0, y'(0)=0$ and $u$ is the heaviside function.

The answer in the back of the book is:

$y=\frac 16((2sin(t)-sin(2t)) - u_\pi(t)(2sin(t)+sin(2t))$

I don't understand why the $(2sin(t)+sin(2t)$ terms that are being multiplied by the heaviside function aren't shifted by $\pi$?

Shouldn't the answer be 
$y=\frac 16((2sin(t)-sin(2t)) - u_\pi(t)(2sin(t-\pi)+sin(2(t-\pi))$?

I worry that I'm not correctly understanding what it actually means to shift a function.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall,

$$\sin(t -\pi) = - \sin t$$

We then have:

$$\mathscr{L}( u_\pi(t) \sin(t-\pi) ) = \mathscr{L}( -u_\pi(t) \sin(t) ) = -e^{-\pi s} \mathscr{L}(- \sin(t)) = e^{-\pi s} \dfrac{1}{s^2+1}$$

So, for the LHS, we have:

$$\mathscr{L} ( y'' + 4y) = s^2 y(s) - sy(s) - y'(0) + 4y(s) = (s^2 + 4)y(s)$$

For the RHS, we have:

$$\mathscr{L} (\sin t + u_\pi(t)\sin(t-\pi)) = \mathscr{L} (\sin t -u_\pi(t) \sin(t))  = \dfrac{e^{-\pi s}+1}{s^2+1}$$

Putting this together yields:

$$y(s) = \dfrac{e^{-\pi s}+1}{(s^2+1)(s^2+4)}$$

The partial fraction expansion is then:

$$y(s) = \dfrac{e^{-\pi s}+1}{(s^2+1)(s^2+4)} = \dfrac{1}{3(s^2+1)} - \dfrac{1}{3(s^2+4)} + \dfrac{e^{-\pi s}}{3(s^2+1)} - \dfrac{e^{-\pi s}}{3(s^2+4)}$$

Comment: Ohh okay, so if I'm understanding this correctly, when you take the inverse transform of that last term, you would get -u_pi(sin(t-pi)) which simplifies to u_pi(sin(t))?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Absolutely, thanks a lot!

Comment: Needs a TU ! (I've earned four big fat zeros myself, just this morning!) +1